# how to open program (matlab) using java?

Tags: java, matlab

i have project in matlab (neural network) but my GUI is using java (netbeans) and i want to open my matlab project using that GUI. can anyone show me the code to open matlab or other program using java. thanks

Comment: SO is for Q&A, not for people to "show you the code". If this problem requires code, edit your post so it follows this format:

What are you trying to do?

What is the problem?

**What have you tried?**

Comment: add your attempts, please. We needn't do your work

Answer (score 0):

You'd want something like this:

```
Runtime runTime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process process = runTime.exec("matlab");        
process.destroy(); // to kill the app
```